# How to generate Staticpages controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

1.I work on ruby-2.0.0 rails-4.0
2.I follow the tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top
3.I ran the "bundle install" command.
4.Here is the output of "bundle install" command

```
user@user-Latitude-E6410:~/rais_project/sample_app$ bundle install
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activesupport (4.0.3)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.3)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.4)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using actionmailer (4.0.3)
Using activemodel (4.0.3)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.2)
Using activerecord (4.0.3)
Using mini_portile (0.5.2)
Using nokogiri (1.6.1)
Using xpath (2.0.0)
Using capybara (2.1.0)
Using ffi (1.9.3)
Using childprocess (0.5.1)
Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (4.0.3)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using diff-lcs (1.2.5)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using jbuilder (1.0.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using bundler (1.5.2)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.11.0)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using rails (4.0.3)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using rspec-core (2.13.1)
Using rspec-expectations (2.13.0)
Using rspec-mocks (2.13.1)
Using rspec-rails (2.13.1)
Using rubyzip (0.9.9)
Using sass (3.2.14)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using websocket (1.0.7)
Using selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)
Using sqlite3 (1.3.8)
Using turbolinks (1.1.1)
Using uglifier (2.1.1)
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

5.Next I ran this command
 "$ rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework".

The output must have come as shown below according to the tutorials

```
  create  app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb
   route  get "static_pages/help"
   route  get "static_pages/home"
  invoke  erb
  create    app/views/static_pages
  create    app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb
  create    app/views/static_pages/help.html.erb
  invoke  helper
  create    app/helpers/static_pages_helper.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  create      app/assets/javascripts/static_pages.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  create      app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss
```

But I got the output as

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:7:in `<module:Handlers>': uninitialized constant Erubis (NameError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:6:in `<class:Template>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:5:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers.rb:10:in `extended'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:97:in `extend'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:97:in `<class:Template>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:7:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder_template.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder.rb:340:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder.rb:340:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/user/rais_project/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

6.I tried with the next command in the tutorial "$ rails generate controller static_pages  ..." for which a controller called "static_pages_controller.rb" must have been generated.
The output of "$ rails generate controller static_pages ..." is

```
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:7:in `<module:Handlers>': uninitialized constant Erubis (NameError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:6:in `<class:Template>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:5:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers.rb:10:in `extended'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:97:in `extend'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:97:in `<class:Template>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:7:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder_template.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder.rb:340:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder.rb:340:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/user/rais_project/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
user@user-Latitude-E6410:~/rais_project/sample_app$ clear

user@user-Latitude-E6410:~/rais_project/sample_app$ $ rails generate controller static_pages ...
$: command not found
user@user-Latitude-E6410:~/rais_project/sample_app$  rails generate controller static_pages ...
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:7:in `<module:Handlers>': uninitialized constant Erubis (NameError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:6:in `<class:Template>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:5:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers/erb.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template/handlers.rb:10:in `extended'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:97:in `extend'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:97:in `<class:Template>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:7:in `<module:ActionView>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_view/template.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder_template.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder.rb:340:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/jbuilder-1.0.2/lib/jbuilder.rb:340:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
    from /home/user/rais_project/sample_app/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

But this controller is not generated.Can you please help?

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Comment: `bundle exec rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework` ?

Comment: I executed this command but no controller was generated

Comment: Your error is actually given here: `uninitialized constant Erubis (NameError)`.  Post your Gemfile and maybe edit the question to see if someone can help.  A quick google shows it might be to do with the tilt gem.

Comment: My Gemfile contains this   "source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end"

Comment: I don't have enough information to fully diagnose, but perhaps try `require 'erubis'` at the top of your controller (e.g. at the top of `app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb` )

Comment: Please edit your question to include your Gemfile - it's impossible to read within a comment.

Comment: I've icluded the Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't have the reputation to comment, but it looks to me like your typing the $ here:

```
user@user-Latitude-E6410:~/rais_project/sample_app$ $ rails generate controller static_pages ...
$: command not found
```

You might be typing it twice. Remember, on Linux, you don't need to type it every time. Although the second time you did not. So I've no idea.

I only got started with rails one year ago. My advice to you is:

Make sure you are running an easy version of Linux, e.g, Ubuntu or Mint. 
Install with RVM. Follow the tutorial exactly. Become familiar with the Terminal & the Shell.
Honestly, this looks like some kind of configuration error.

I don't think your issue is with the command your using to generate your controller, but something farther back in the tutorial.

I would suggest taking a deep breath, and slowing retracing your steps through the tutorial. I think this is just a configuration issue. (Just me guessing.) Stay cool, and have fun with rails!